# Unable to parse string to JSON

Tags: go

I am dynamically getting a string as an input and I need to access certain fields, so I'm trying to parse it to JSON, but my code is not working.

I need the ability to fetch values of certain fields like input['school_id'] and need to covert the value of input['school_details'] into a map[string]string. This is what I tried:

```
func main() {
    input := `{"school_capacity":2000,"school_id":"10","school_details":{"classes":"8","subjects":"5","teachers":"15"}}`

    var raw map[string]string

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &raw)

    print(raw["input"])
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Try using `fmt.println` instead of `print`. I tried it and it seemed to unmarshall the school_id since "10" is a string, but failed with school_capacity and school_details. Switching to `map[string]interface{}` should fix that though. Getting the details of `school_details` should be easy by "casting" it to map[string]interface{} with `raw["school_details"].(map[string]interface{})["classes"]`.

Comment: Never ignore errors. `json.Unmarshal` gives you an error that will indicate what is wrong. Read it.

Comment: Also, a note on terminlogy:  "parse to JSON" makes no sense.  You have JSON. You need to parse it _from_ JSON to something else (a map in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    input := `{"school_capacity":2000,"school_id":"10","school_details":{"classes":"8","subjects":"5","teachers":"15"}}`

    var raw map[string]interface{}

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &raw)

    fmt.Printf("%v", raw)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are unmarshalling a map of strings to strings. Your data has an integer field, a string field, and a struct field. So if any of the data fails to parse, you get an empty string. Additionally, there is no "input" field, which you are trying to access.

One of the best ways of marshaling and unmarshaling data with a fixed structure is to use struct tags:

```golang
type response struct {
    Page   int      `json:"page"`
    Fruits []string `json:"fruits"`
}
```

But you can also use a map to empty interface:

```golang
var dat map[string]interface{}
```

Example source: https://gobyexample.com/json

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `map[string]interface{}` to store your JSON object. `map[string]string` won't handle elements that are numeric, boolean or nested objects.

Having done that you can look at the elements of the map:

```
fmt.Print(raw["school_details"])
```

and you can pull nested objects out using a type assertion, effectively casting the nested object to a `map[string]interface{}`:

```
if schoolDetails, ok := raw["school_details"].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", schoolDetails["classes"])
}
```

It's a bit messy working with arbitrary JSON objects so you'll need to step carefully to make sure the structure is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

That's worked: https://repl.it/@ruoyanss/jsonParse

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
  str := `{"school_capacity":2000,"school_id":"10","school_details":{"classes":"8","subjects":"5","teachers":"15"}}`

  var raw map[string]interface{}

  json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &raw)

  fmt.Println(raw["school_capacity"])
}
```